# Does the Name Engraved Ring help or hinder general Coop?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Ok so I understand the mechanic of the name engraved ring; to help players connect over a wider spectrum of Soul Memory. But I was wondering if it hinders players who aren't wearing the ring? Eg, if I was wearing the ring, and mt friend wasn't, and we were within Soul Memory range of each other (without the ring) could he still connect to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ring is designed for organised co op. My interpretation is that it is a fix/improvement to the original co op system as if friends wanted to play together in Dark Souls 1, it could take several minutes for the summon sign to show up if at all, not to mention the floor usually being crowded with signs in popular areas.

From my personal experience with the ring it completely blocks all co operation apart from with people in the same group as the wearer. All I could see when I was playing with my friend was his sign and maybe 1 other in rare occasions even in popular areas.

Another point to consider is that it also blocks all NPC signs, so if you are looking for 'general' co op and level progression where you would want to include NPC's, I wouldn't recommend it.